# Changing MAC address to some specific addresses causes slow down

Tags: networking, mac-address

I need to change my MAC address constantly to test something and when I spoof/ghost my MAC address to some of the addresses that have the prefix of F4-6D-04-D4, my download speed gets either very slow or almost disconnect or something like throttled in which it goes to max speed for 2 seconds then stops for 10 seconds and repeat.

Since all the MAC addresses I have problem with have that prefix, I was wondering if you guys might suspect something.

Comment: Does that weird slowdown happen with anything starting with `F4:6D:04` or with just `F4:6D:04:D4` (MAC-address prefixes tend to be three bytes per vendor. In this case F4:6D:04 means Asustek). Also, any other devices on the network (unlikely that you are using the same MAC address as an already existing device, but worth checking).

Comment: It's F4:6D:04.

I didn't understand your second question.

Comment: MAC addresses need to be unique.  Did you happen to use a MAC from another device which is already on your LAN? That would confuse the a MAC table in a switch and that might cause [performance] issues.

Comment: Yes, that is the whole point of ghosting/spoofing. I want to have same MAC address as another computer/device. It works for some addresses and has this weird slowdown on these ones.

Comment: @idn All bets are off if two devices have the same mac address. Don't do that.

Comment: @davidpostill but A) it's works for other mac addresses and B) it's a valid method that even works for "other" things (don't want to spread non-ethical methods).